# InteractivePopGestureRecognizer issue on swiping back

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, ios16, xcode14

I'm navigating to a details screen from chat messages screen. The chat message screen contains custom keyboard which will be presented when chat messages screen is opened. On navigating the screen from chat to details screen everything works fine. When I try to navigate to previous screen(chat screen) using interactivePopGestureRecognizer, keyboard appears on top before the current navigation completes. How to fix this?

I tried by hiding the custom keyboard by hiding based on gesture progress, didn't worked.

Comment: into chat screen -> viewWillDisappear(_:) - use self.view.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: Please share your code of both controllers for better understanding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. The issue is happening only in xcode 14, other xcode versions are working fine.